# I coudn't get slide show images on my html page

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to create a small website for that I've added below code in my html for getting slide show images.

I get only slides but images doesn't display, I couldn't understand what causes the problem.
so, please can anyone give me a solution for this problem.

should I make any changes in below code.

is java script needed for this code ?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        /* a:active {
            color: white;
        }
        a:visited {
            color: blue;
        } */
        a {
            display: blue;
    }
    
    body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: #34495e;
    }
    .slidershow{
      width: 700px;
      height: 400px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .middle{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
    .navigation{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      display: flex;
    }
    .bar{
      width: 50px;
      height: 10px;
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      margin: 6px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }
    .bar:hover{
      background: #fff;
    }
    
    input[name="r"]{
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    .slides{
      width: 500%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .slide{
      width: 20%;
      transition: 0.6s;
    }
    .slide img{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    #r1:checked ~ .s1{
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    #r2:checked ~ .s1{
      margin-left: -20%;
    }
    #r3:checked ~ .s1{
      margin-left: -40%;
    }
    #r4:checked ~ .s1{
      margin-left: -60%;
    }
    #r5:checked ~ .s1{
      margin-left: -80%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <div class="slidershow middle">
    
          <div class="slides">
            <input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" checked>
            <input type="radio" name="r" id="r2">
            <input type="radio" name="r" id="r3">
            <input type="radio" name="r" id="r4">
            <input type="radio" name="r" id="r5">
            <div class="slide s1">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/09f/fff.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/09f/fff.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/09f/fff.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/09f/fff.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300/09f/fff.png" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="navigation">
            <label for="r1" class="bar"></label>
            <label for="r2" class="bar"></label>
            <label for="r3" class="bar"></label>
            <label for="r4" class="bar"></label>
            <label for="r5" class="bar"></label>
          </div>
        </div>
     
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you providing correct path of images ?

Comment: @SudhirOjha I've given image name only.